# What is the working principle of g-suits?

Tags: pilots, pilot-technique, maneuver

Pilots since world wars have been wearing g-suits in fighter planes to minimize the effect of high g encountered by them during close maneuvers.

1. How do g-suits help in minimizing the effect of high g's on the pilots?
2. What is the maximum g that a g-suit could handle properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do g-suits help in minimizing the effect of high g's on the pilots?

G-suit create extra external pressure on the limbs (legs in particular) to prevent the blood to stagnate far from the heart. In normal conditions specific [biological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal-muscle_pump) [systems](http://www.cvphysiology.com/Cardiac%20Function/CF017.htm) automatically return the blood from the extremities to the heart, but when subjected to high G loads these systems fail, as they are not designed for such conditions.

By creating pressure on the body the G-suit **alleviates** the G load perceived by the body.

> What is the maximum g that a g-suit could handle properly?

The main limitation is not only the amount of Gs, but for how long the human body can sustain them (spoiler alert: not much)

[image]

<sup>Image [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force#Human_tolerance_of_g-force)</sup>

As you can see the Gs usually experienced in a fighter aircraft (blue line, see diagram on top right) cannot be sustained much beyond 3 seconds if they are of even moderate intensity. The G-suits help the body resist slightly longer.

Comment: What's interesting to me here is how the F-16 seat (and less so the F-22) is tilted back to turn some of the Gs experienced in the blue direction into Gs in the more forgiving red direction.

Comment: @ToddWilcox please don't get confused by the diagram: to "convert" blue into red you should tilt the seat forward, not backwards.

Comment: Blue is positive Gs driving blood towards the feet, right? Wouldn't that make red indicate Gs driving blood towards the back/spine (eyeballs in)?

Comment: @ToddWilcox blue (up) drives the blood down, I then understand that red (back) would drive the blood in front.

Comment: That does make sense in terms of the diagram, but not in terms of actual G tolerances of humans. Hmmm...

Comment: @ToddWilcox I agree with you, but I cannot find a better diagram. If you can, I will update my answer.

Comment: Isn't that diagram missing the forward-acceleration line?  Also, why does the acceleration tolerance drop off dramatically for very brief exposures?

Comment: @Sean yes, it is missing, I could not find one with that included. For the why part, I think you better ask on biology or health, I cannot answer that.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to what @Federico wrote, g-suits press the legs by using inflatable sacs sewed in the suit. The suit is connected to a valve on the aircraft (or spaceship). When g forces increase, the valve pushes more air to the sacs and inflates them.

As for the limit, I think it is 9 g's but I don't have any citations. Also bear in mind that g limit has to do with other parameters as well, such as cockpit and seat design like HAC (high acceleration cockpit).

Comment: More primitive suits use liquid or gel; as Gs increase, the gel is forced downwards toward the legs. It's also interesting to note that they can't always be used; the inflation of the leg cuffs in the G-suit can restrict movement of a center stick, so the Blue Angels famously do not wear them, and "graduation day" involves staying awake through a max-G 360 turn. The Thunderbirds do use them, as the F-16 has a side stick.